# Magento2.2.3 Customer custome attribute value not save

Tags: attributes, magento2.2.3

Custom customer attribute is created but values are not being saved from admin customer account information tab.

I did check into database tables for `eav_attribute` and `customer_eav_attribute` and attributes are created properly

**=> InstallData.php file**

```
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface 
{
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Config
     */
    private $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Installs data for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $setup->startSetup();

        $attributeCode = 'account_id';
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, 'account_id', [
            'label' => 'Account Id',
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => 1,
            'system' => 0,
            'position' => 100,
            'input' => 'text'
        ]);

        $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
            null,
            $attributeCode);

        $amountId = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode);
        $amountId->setData('used_in_forms', [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]);
        $amountId->getResource()->save($amountId);

        $attributeCode = 'amount_spend';

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode, [
            'label' => 'Amount Spent',
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => 1,
            'system' => 0,
            'position' => 110
        ]);

        $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
            null,
            $attributeCode);

        $amountSpend = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode);
        $amountSpend->setData('used_in_forms', [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]);
        $amountSpend->getResource()->save($amountSpend);
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for me work this:
InstallData.php

```
namespace UseApp\OldOrdersSum\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'customattr', [
            'type' => 'decimal',
            'label' => 'Custom Attr',
            'input' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'customattr')
        ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer'
            ]
        ]);
        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```